# Convert a regex match repaceAll() to replace() for sonar rule

Tags: java, regex, sonarqube

I have a Java String that is converted to ssn format via `input.replaceAll("(\\d{3})(\\d{2})(\\d{4})","$1-$2-$3")` which is flagged by sonar rule as described in title. Just substituting the replace does not work, so I'm looking for a solution here.

Comment: Ignore the flag.

Comment: [The applicable SonarQube rule](https://cloud-ci.sgs.com/sonar/coding_rules?open=java%3AS5361&rule_key=java%3AS5361) is that `String.replace()` should be preferred to `String.replaceAll()` *when the first argument is not a regex*.  That is not your case, so the flag is either conditional or altogether spurious.  Either way, it's reasonable to ignore it.

Comment: However, you could consider pre-compiling a `java.util.regex.Pattern` once, and holding it somewhere for reuse, instead of compiling the pattern every time you want to perform such a replacement as `replaceAll()` will do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it by using precompiled *Pattern* and *Matcher*, or by substring without regex.

```java
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String input = "123456789";

        // Approach 1: Using precompiled Pattern and Matcher
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(\\d{3})(\\d{2})(\\d{4})");
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input);
        String ssnFormattedPattern = matcher.replaceAll("$1-$2-$3");
        System.out.println("Using Pattern and Matcher: " + ssnFormattedPattern);

        // Approach 2: Using substring without regex
        String ssnFormattedSubstring = input.substring(0, 3) + "-" + input.substring(3, 5) + "-" + input.substring(5);
        System.out.println("Using substring: " + ssnFormattedSubstring);
    }
}
```